# npm in browser causing module specifier error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, blockchain, node-modules

I have imported a module into my project. When running it separately it works fine. As soon as I want to use it in the browser it causes problems.

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "theblockchainapi". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

This is how my import looks:

`<script type="module" src="./app.js"></script>`

the app.js starts with:

`import theblockchainapi from 'theblockchainapi';`

Answer (score 2):

Change from:

```js
import theblockchainapi from 'theblockchainapi';
```

to:

```js
const theblockchainapi = require('theblockchainapi');
```

Comment: That will only result in "require is not defined"